# DOJO custom modules development with xdomain

Tags: javascript, dojo

I have this situation:

- application server running on example.com - this is where html pages
  are loaded from m
- server for serving static files on static.example.com - this is from where are static files loaded from (css, graphics, scripts)

I want to run DOJO with my custom modules on my site. The problem is that I need xdomain build for everything i want to use (dojo, dijit, dojox, custom modules).
It would be alright, to create xdomain build for production enviorment, but I need to have this two domain split also for development.

Ok, I can prebuild dojo,dijit,dojox with xdomain loader. But rebuilding custom modules all the time for development is not probably the right way.

So, what do you recommend me? Or, what exactly does the builder do, for achieving module to load xdomain? Can i create module to work xdomain directly?

Thank you

Comment: I don't get it... if everything is from example.com isn't it same domain?

Comment: the static content (dojo scripts) is from domain static.example.com. This is taken by browser as different domain or not? :-O

Comment: Ahh you were maybe confused, because formatting was wrong. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Dojo 1.7 (on the download site, not yet announced)  The new AMD-based loader enables cross domain code without the special XD build tool, which used to generate a transform a bit like AMD.